# How to conditionally pass data in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to console my data `onApplyClick` event. It is working fine when I am passing all the data but when I an trying to pass data conditionally then it is throwing error.

My main component code is

```
            <MyComponent
                onApplyClick={(
                    myData: First & {
                        newData: Second;
                    }
                ) => console.log(myData)}
                getData={getData}       
            />
```

Where First & Second is an interface. Now I am passing all data using `onApplyClick` event like -

```
            onApplyClick={() => {
                let AData= {
                    first: "one",
                    second: "two
                };
                onApplyClick({
                    newData: AData,
                    Bdata: "three",
                    Cdata: "four"
                });
            }}
```

Second interface is -

```
export interface Second  {
    first : string;
    second: string;
}
```

First interface is -

```
export interface First {
    Bdata? : string;
    Cdata? :string;
}
```

now I want to pass Bdata if a condition is true & if condition is false then I want to pass Cdata `onApplyClick`.

I am trying pass data using this code -

```
                onApplyClick({
                    newData: AData,
                    if(condition==true) {
                      Bdata: "three",
                    }
                    else {
                      Cdata: "four"
                    }
                });
```

I am getting error while passing the condition inside an `onApplyClick` event. How can I pass data conditionally ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best approach in this case would be to create two callbacks with defferetnt data.

Or create condition with data:

```
const data = condition ? data1: data2;
```

And then pass it in callback.

```
onClick={() => callback(data)}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <MyComponent
         onApplyClick={( condition ?  { myData: First}:{ newData: Second}) => console.log(myData)}
         getData={getData}       
            />
```

Comment: I want to make condition in newData only. Only in Bdata & Cdata.

Comment: what do you mean condition in newData only , what is your desired output

Comment: desired output would be either onApplyClick({
                    newData: AData
                      Bdata: "three"
                }); or onApplyClick({
                    newData: AData
                      Cdata: "four"
                });

Comment: you mean onApplyClick({ newData: AData , Bdata: "three" }); or onApplyClick({ newData: AData , Cdata: "four" });

Answer (score 0):

You can't have conditionals inside an object. What you need to do is take that condition outside of the object and return different objects in each clause.

```
onApplyClick( condition ? {newData: AData, Bdata: "three"} : {newData: AData, Cdata: "four"} )
```

Comment: Can you give me an example in this scenario ?

Comment: @AnuragMishra I added an example.